# CI4 - Session ID is always the same

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-cookies

I am trying to debug a problem that I have with user sessions in CI4.0.4 app. When a user is logged in and another user logs in, the old user is switched to the newly entered user settings (name etc). This happens because instead of creating a new session file on the server, the new user is overwriting the same session file.

Trying to get to the bottom of this I noticed a strange thing:

- I logged out all users
- I deleted the cookies and all session files from the server
- I logged in with one of the users and I got the same session file name as the one previously generated (2vu0gmmmcrl1f9hqqqof0js3m8b135gb)
- I suspected that I missed something and I repeated the experiment, same result
- I have tried all the steps above with another user and another browser, same result, the session filename is always 2vu0gmmmcrl1f9hqqqof0js3m8b135gb.

Somehow CI is reffering every user to the same session and therefore the app doesn't work for concurrent users.

These are the settings from app\Config\App:

```
public $sessionDriver            = 'CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\FileHandler';
public $sessionCookieName        = 'ci_session';
public $sessionExpiration        = 7200;
public $sessionSavePath          = WRITEPATH . 'session';
public $sessionMatchIP           = false;
public $sessionTimeToUpdate      = 300;
public $sessionRegenerateDestroy = true;
public $cookiePrefix   = '';
public $cookieDomain   = 'library.agilepractice.ro';
public $cookiePath     = '/';
public $cookieSecure   = false;
public $cookieHTTPOnly = false;
```

Comment: I have a question are you using the same browser for both users?

Comment: No. One user is logged in with Chrome, the other with Firefox. Strange enough, now I see that the response header for a competely different subdomain (blabla.agilepractice.ro)  has this:
`Set-Cookie:
ci_session=2vu0gmmmcrl1f9hqqqof0js3m8b135gb; Domain=library.agilepractice.ro; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=none`

Comment: Please change `public $cookieDomain   = 'library.agilepractice.ro';` to `public $cookieDomain = '';` in `app\Config\App.php`

Comment: I just did it. No impact, same issue.